# Javascript variable doesn't add values as it should

Tags: javascript, variables

I have this code in html and javascript
HTML

```js
function getResult() {
  let answer_one = document.getElementById("question_one").value;
  let correct_ans = 0;
  let result = "You answered " + correct_ans + " correctly.";

  if (answer_one === "abuja") {
    correct_ans++;
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="question1">
    <p>What is the capital of Nigeria</p><br>
    <input type="text" id="question_one">

  </div>

  <button id="button" onclick="getResult();">Submit</button>

</div>
<!--end of container-->

<div class="button_after">

  <h1 id="result"></h1>

</div>
<!--end of button_after-->
```

my issue is that the correct_ans variable doesn't add when i type in the correct answer in the textbox

Comment: You create your result phrase before you calculate the result. It’s always going to be 0 when done in this order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize the variable `result` after you check for the correct answer.

```js
function getResult() {
  let correct_ans = 0;
  let answer_one = document.getElementById("question_one").value;  
  if (answer_one === "abuja") correct_ans++;

  let result = "You answered " + correct_ans + " correctly.";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="question1">
    <p>What is the capital of Nigeria</p><br>
    <input type="text" id="question_one">

  </div>

  <button id="button" onclick="getResult();">Submit</button>

</div>
<!--end of container-->

<div class="button_after">

  <h1 id="result"></h1>

</div>
<!--end of button_after-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared the variable `abuja` before you updated the variable `correct_ans`. Put it after the `if` condition. If you'll add other questions you need to put the initial declaration of `correct_ans = 0` out of the function or you're always going to get 0 or 1.

```js
function getResult() {
  let answer_one = document.getElementById("question_one").value;
  
  let correct_ans = 0;
  
  if (answer_one === "abuja") {
    correct_ans++;
  }
  let result = "You answered " + correct_ans + " correctly.";

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="question1">
    <p>What is the capital of Nigeria</p><br>
    <input type="text" id="question_one">

  </div>

  <button id="button" onclick="getResult();">Submit</button>

</div>
<!--end of container-->

<div class="button_after">

  <h1 id="result"></h1>

</div>
<!--end of button_after-->
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, result was evaluated before the correct_ans increment.
Try this instead.

```
function getResult() {
  let answer_one = document.getElementById("question_one").value;
  let correct_ans = 0;
  let result = "";

  if (answer_one === "abuja") {
    correct_ans++;
  }
  result = You answered " + correct_ans + " correctly.
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}
```